Recommended way to include binaries in flutter application and how to access them
As there doesn't seem to exist much regarding this I meant to ask what is recommended in this case? I have been including it in /lib/bin, accessing it using join(dirname(Platform.script.toFilePath()), 'lib', 'bin', 'binary');
However, this does not seem to be working in the general case. Does anyone have experience with this?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

After a lot of experimentation, the following seems to be the best way to achieve it:
    Platform.resolvedExecutable.replaceFirst(RegExp(r'/[^/]+$'), ''),
    '..',
    'Frameworks',
    'App.framework',
    'Resources',
    'flutter_assets',
    'assets',
    'bin',
    'yourBinary');

This can be used after adding assets/bin/ to your pubspec.yaml
